# Use GTK3 in a snapcraft app

Tags: gtk3, snap

How can I use Gtk3 in my snap app? should I add Gtk3 as a plugin to `snapcraft.yaml`? and how to build it?
However I can build Gtk3 outside of snapcraft system.

Comment: I add Gtk3 dependency with autotools, but snappy have some problems with gtk applications https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapcraft/+bug/1584357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/galculator/snapcraft.yaml - it's actually quite straight-forward:

The relevant bit is

`parts:
  galculator:
    source: https://github.com/galculator/galculator.git
    plugin: autotools
    install-via: prefix
    build-packages:
      - flex
      - gettext
      - intltool
      - libgtk-3-dev
      - libpng12-dev
      - libxml-parser-perl
    stage-packages:
      - libglib2.0-0
      - libgtk-3-0
      - libpango-1.0-0
      - libpng12-0
      - libquadmath0
      - dconf-gsettings-backend
      - librsvg2-common
      - libwmf0.2-7-gtk
      - libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
after: [gtkconf]`

A few points:
 - it uses the `autotools` plugin to build the package
 - it pulls in `libgtk3-dev` (and other packages) as `build-packages`, so packages you need to have locally installed to build the snap
 - it mentions dependencies as `stage-packages` which are then bundled with the snap
 - it uses the `gtkconf` wiki part for the launcher

Have a look at [the full example](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/galculator) though, it should help getting your GTK3 app to build.

Comment: This answer is now out of date